# All calls from Viber and Skype are appearing as normal calls after updating to iOS 10. How do I disable this?

Tags: iphone, ios, call

After updating my iPhone 6 to iOS 10, all calls coming from Viber and Skype are appearing in the calls list as normal phone calls. Also, when I'm on a Viber call and a real phone call comes, I don't get notified. Before iOS 10 it used to mute Viber and give me a notification than someone is calling.  How do I return back to these settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved automatically, I am not sure if it is because of IOS 10.1.1 or an update to viber app, currently it gives me a waiting beep/screen while I am on viber call and getting a normal call, didn't test yet with other apps like skype/whatsapp

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to revert back to old settings now. I have opened a ticket with apple to get the users freedom to either use or not use. The setting like Setting -> Phone -> Service provider makes perfect sense. Lets see if apple provides this capabilities or not.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I messed up and this is an article from an ios10 preview version. This setting seems to not exist anymore. So as far as I know, reverting to the old way is not possible :/

---

This change is due to Viber and Skype now using CallKit which you can read up on [here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/08/11/ios-10-preview-phone-app/).

In that article it says this:

> It’s important to note that Apple won’t force you to let any VoIP app integrate with Phone without your permission. Just like you must authorize third-party apps to access your camera or microphone, CallKit-enabled apps will put up a new type of iOS prompt at first run asking for permission to use CallKit.

Makes perfect sense in my eyes. A little further down they say this:

> Any VoIP apps that you’ve permitted to use CallKit will honor your current Do Not Disturb setting and a list of blocked contacts. Lastly, you can revoke these permissions for VoIP apps by flipping switches in **Settings → Phone → Service Providers**.

So going to Service Providers and disabling access to CallKit should revert it back to the way you want.

Comment: I can't find Service Providers under settings -> phone

Comment: @AmrElgarhy hmm seems you are right, I can't seem to find them on my phone either. But I don't see why that setting would not exist, ill try poking around more and let you know.

Comment: @AmrElgarhy I quickly installed skype and it seems like apple removed the whole "apps need permission to use CallKit" after ios10 beta 3, the article I linked and quoted happens to be from before that change, so my bad, I guess I should check better next time.
However this now leads me to believe that it's not possible to revert back to the old way.

Comment: that's really bad from apple to do such thing, it is really an annoying feature

Answer (score 1):

At least for Skype you can disable callkit integration by opening the Skype app and going to "My info" -> Settings -> disable "Integrated calling".

Answer (score -3):

In IOS 8.0.1, call logs can be deleted for everyone in viber, after that you wont be able to see calls or messages that has been made :)

Comment: That unfortunately tells us nothing of how it works in iOS 10.